# UITableView with Horizontally wrapping cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, word-wrap

I am looking for how to, in Swift and Interface Builder, create a UITableView in Xcode where the table has a set width (example: padding to left and right edges of superview might be 8).  In the table, I want cells to go across the first row.  When a new cell can no longer fit in the first row I want it to go to the second row.  When a new cell can no longer fit on the second row, I want it to go to the third row, etc. I only want the table to scroll vertically.

If anyone can point me to examples or documentation on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `UICollectionView`.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/